# how to add total column and another total row to the bottom to pivot table in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pivot

```
declare @sql as varchar(max)
declare @sizename as varchar(max)
declare @total as varchar(max)
declare @articleno as varchar(max)

select @sizename =

 QUOTENAME(SizeName)
FROM
(
Select Sizename from SIZESET left join SHIPMENTSIZESET on SIZESET.SizeSetID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.SizeSetID
left join SHIPMENTSCHED on SHIPMENTSCHED.ShipmentSchedID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.ShipmentSchedID 
left join DESIGN on DESIGN.DesignID = SIZESET.DesignID 
left join ARTICLE on ARTICLE.DesignID = DESIGN.DesignID where articleno = 'EZT02'
) as B
order by b.SizeName

SELECT @total = 
coalesce (@total + ', Sum(','Sum(')+ QUOTENAME(cast(Sizename as varchar(10)))+') as '+QUOTENAME(cast(Sizename as varchar(10)))

FROM
(
    Select startdate as [Start Date], enddate as [End Date], SizeName, quantity
from SIZESET left join SHIPMENTSIZESET on SIZESET.SizeSetID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.SizeSetID
left join SHIPMENTSCHED on SHIPMENTSCHED.ShipmentSchedID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.ShipmentSchedID 
left join DESIGN on DESIGN.DesignID = SIZESET.DesignID 
left join ARTICLE on ARTICLE.DesignID = DESIGN.DesignID where articleno = 'EZT02'


) as B

select @articleno = 
 QUOTENAME(SizeName)
FROM
(
Select Sizename from Sizeset join SHIPMENTSIZESET on SHIPMENTSIZESET.SizeSetID = SIZESET.SizeSetID
) as B

set @sql = 'With PivotData As
            (
                Select startdate as [Start Date], enddate as [End Date], SizeName, quantity
                from SIZESET left join SHIPMENTSIZESET on SIZESET.SizeSetID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.SizeSetID
                left join SHIPMENTSCHED on SHIPMENTSCHED.ShipmentSchedID = SHIPMENTSIZESET.ShipmentSchedID 
                left join DESIGN on DESIGN.DesignID = SIZESET.DesignID 
                left join ARTICLE on ARTICLE.DesignID = DESIGN.DesignID where articleno = '+@articleno+'

            )
            Select *
            From
            (
                Select startdate as [Start Date], enddate as [End Date], '+ @sizename +'
                from PivotData
                Pivot
                (
                    Sum(Quantity) for Sizename in('+@sizename+')
                ) as PivotResult

                Union All
                select ''Grand Total'', '+@total+'
                from
                (
                    Select startdate as [Start Date], enddate as [End Date], '+ @sizename +'
                from PivotData
                Pivot
                (
                    Sum(Quantity) for Sizename in('+@sizename+')
                ) as PivotResult

                )tot
            )src
            '
            exec(@sql)
```

i just follow some codes related in creating pivot table but error appeared 
Invalid column name 'Extra Large'

Comment: Can you replace the last line with `SELECT @sql` and show us what @sql contains?

Comment: it contains the codes from the With Pivot Data
i cannot paste it, too long. :(
is it important?

Comment: You have got an error. `Extra Large`, I assume is one of the sizes in your SIZESET table, that when combined with the existing table causes some issues. My best guess is that this size appears twice. BTW, you can always edit the original question.

Comment: yes it is, it works fine when i did not put the total column and row. i dont have any idea why it has something to do with adding of total. thanks btw